# coredata - save content as json string or nsdata

Tags: ios, core-data

In my iOS app I've got a server sending me json messages.
I decode those json messages and built a custom object from.

Amongst the json data I also get a property of custom objects which get decoded differently by different controllers, so I'd rather keep that information decoded / in raw format and not build a custom class from it.

I wish to save the object and its custom data to a local database using coredata. I'm now contemplating the two alternatives.

1. Saving the custom data as raw NSString property of larger object
2. Saving the custom data as NSData property of larger object

With which one should I go? What's the best practice here?

Comment: If core data is introducing complexity, why dont you keep the json in file.txt . I think that will be easier one..

Comment: I want to add core-data none the less, given that what would be the best way to store that custom data?

Comment: Go with raw nstring I believe

Comment: @Rajan say why you believe that to be the best option

Comment: Frankly speaking, it came out as a random choice. Just something that was in my mind is that we have to deal with nsstrings when we write something in label or table. On fetching nsdata , we have to go through one more process of converting that to a string. I dont know I am correct, If you find me wrong, please correct me by commenting below

Comment: @Rajan It's certainly an option, but the conversion from JSON string, which you are unlikely to display directly, is more time consuming than direct usage of the data

Comment: @Wain ok. Thanks. Can you please provide any sort of link or video or tutorial which explains the matter how to use and implement that you have answered for this question using core data. I haven't used transformable type of thing, just want to learn. Thanks

Comment: Just set the transformable data type and it will work for you, archiving is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transformable attribute and store the data as either the array or dictionary you unpack from the JSON. It isn't very efficient accessing this attribute directly (you will incur an archiving overhead) so you should add a transient attribute to cache the value after first access.